# Android Studio - How to programmatically add layout_below param to CardViews inside a PercentRelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I am here because I am trying to set programmatically the **layout_below** parameter of some cardViews without success.
These cardViews are located inside a PercentRelativeLayout (I do not know if it is relevant but these cardviews have been added programmatically too).
I show you the code to make it clear.

```
                          ...

<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/prl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:percent="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cv0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        percent:layout_heightPercent="65%"
        percent:layout_marginTopPercent="2%"
        percent:layout_marginLeftPercent="2%"
        percent:layout_marginRightPercent="2%"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:percent="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cv1"

        // here I would like to add android:layout_below="@+id/cv0"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        percent:layout_heightPercent="65%"
        percent:layout_marginTopPercent="2%"
        percent:layout_marginLeftPercent="2%"
        percent:layout_marginRightPercent="2%"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:percent="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cv2"

        // here I would like to add android:layout_below="@+id/cv1"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        percent:layout_heightPercent="65%"
        percent:layout_marginTopPercent="2%"
        percent:layout_marginLeftPercent="2%"
        percent:layout_marginRightPercent="2%"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

                                     ...
```

I tried to do something like this in my Java code but without success.

```
PercentRelativeLayout prl = (PercentRelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.prl);
CardView cv = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.cv_block, prl, false);
cv.setId(currentId++);
prl.addView(cv);

cv = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.cv_block, prl, false);
cv.setId(currentId++);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams cv_lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) cv.getLayoutParams();
cv_lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,currentId-2);

/* I have also tried to call cv.requestLayout() but nothing changed */

prl.addView(cv);
```

As you can see, I am trying to generate cardviews and insert them one below the other.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

PercentRelativeLayout is depreciated, so you are encouraged to use other type of layout.

> This class was deprecated in API level 26.1.0.
>   consider using ConstraintLayout and associated layouts instead. The following shows how to replicate the functionality of percentage layouts with a ConstraintLayout. The Guidelines are used to define each percentage break point, and then a Button view is stretched to fill the gap:

ConstraintLayout gives lots of opportunities.
More about PercentRelativeLayout deprecation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html).
More about ConstraintLayout and how to use it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) or [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XamMbnzI5vE).